# Scrollbar em tela de Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

É possível colocar *scrollbar* num *winforms* para aumentar a quantidade de conteúdo da janela?
Não apenas em um *datagrid*, mas na tela toda para incluir qualquer coisa, como mais botões, campos de texto...

O objetivo é unificar três *tabs* em uma única exibição e ir descendo por um *scrollbar*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você deseja criar uma [barra de rolagem](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barra_de_rolagem).

Você pode fazer isso usando a propriedade [AutoScroll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/a62htd5x(v=vs.110).aspx).

Basta acessar as propriedades do formulário e mudar o valor da propriedade para **True**.

**Exemplo** :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: exatamente isso! um simples true, essas soluções que são as boas, kkkkkkkkkk!